# Rules of column width in tabular

Tags: tables, multicolumn, rules, width, calc

I would like to put rules in a tabular to "strike out" a number of consecutive cells within one row. I want these rules to automatically adjust to column width.

[image]

For example, the width of the first column is determined by `foobar`, the width of the second column is determined by `barbarbar`, and the width of the third column is determined by `foo`. The width of the first rule is `\widthof{barbarbar}+2\tabcolsep+\widthof{foo}` and the width of the second rule is `\widthof{foo}`.

The tabular above is generated by the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
    foo & bar & foo  \\
    foobar & barbarbar \\
    bar & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule[0.5ex]{\widthof{barbarbar}+2\tabcolsep+\widthof{foo}}{0.5pt}} \\
    bar & foo & \rule[0.5ex]{\widthof{foo}}{0.5pt} \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I'm interested in how to automatically get the widths of columns and use them within the same tabular to set the width of the rules so that they don't have to be manually specified as `\widthof{barbarbar}+2\tabcolsep+\widthof{foo}` and `\widthof{foo}`. Thus, if I change `foo` in the last column to `foofoo`, I want the width of the rules to automatically adjust:

[image].

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Probably `\hrulefill`does what you want to achieve?

Comment: what about tikz solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your original code, here are two versions using either `\hrulefill` or `\xhfill` from the `xhfill` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xhfill} % provides the \xrfill command used in the third example
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
    foo & bar & foo  \\
    foobar & barbarbar \\
    bar & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\rule[0.5ex]{\widthof{barbarbar}+2\tabcolsep+\widthof{foo}}{0.5pt}} \\
    bar & foo & \rule[0.5ex]{\widthof{foo}}{0.5pt} \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
    foo & bar & foo  \\
    foobar & barbarbar \\
    bar & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\hrulefill} \\
    bar & foo & \hrulefill \\
\end{tabular}


\begin{tabular}{ l l l }
    foo & bar & foo  \\
    foobar & barbarbar \\
    bar & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\xrfill[0.75ex]{0.2pt}} \\
    bar & foo & \xrfill[0.75ex]{0.2pt} \\
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```